# Prevent FFMPEG from skipping expired frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to save live streams with an .m3u8 url. Regularly I see the following message. This results in the output video freezing.

```
skipping 5 segments ahead, expired from playlists
```

How can I tell ffmpeg to just write the frames and ignore that they are expired? I would rather see a choppy video than having it just freeze.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but WTH... maybe it helps somebody.

If I understand the situation correctly, that message means that ffmpeg is skipping the download of 5 entire chunks ("segments").

It's not about "expired frames", but "chunks that I have scheduled for download, but are no longer published on the playlists".

5 chunks/segments may be several seconds long, and not just 5 frames. That's why you see a freeze.

Perhaps you could try using some filter with the input, so the output muxer may fill the segments gap. Take a look at the overlay filter, for example: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-82

Comment: Ok.  So what I am doing is saving live streamed videos. So how can I tell ffmpeg to retrieve all segments even if they are "expired" and write them to the file in the order they are supposed to appear. Streaming these videos not through ffmpeg produces clear video with no freezing.

Comment: Don't want to down vote, but how is this answer helpful in any way?

Comment: i often view a site that has this issue every time i try to record it with `ffmpeg` (usually via `youtube-dl`).  the web player has no such issues so it is clear to me that the skipped segments are available and have the missing action that shows as a freeze in the recording.  you can see this in the ts number at the end of each URL in the `ffmpeg` log output.  each number differs by 1 for the usual progression but sometimes differs by more which is the number skipped.  but i have no idea how to make `ffmpeg` not skip these segments.  maybe i need to dig into the `ffmpeg` source code.